# Where clause is not working in Hibernate 5 XML Mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I used Hibernate 4 with XML Mapping and the code is:

```
 <map name="scormData" table="scorm_data_attempt" where="current">
        <key>
            <column name="userid" />
            <column name="course_id" />
        </key>
        <composite-map-key class="ScormDataKey">
            <key-property name="scormId" column="scorm_id"
                type="integer" />
            <key-property name="variableName" column="variable_name"
                type="string" />
            <key-property name="attempt" />
        </composite-map-key>
        <element type="string" column="variable_value" />
    </map>
```

However, now when I change to Hibernate 5, the where field is not working anymore and I cannot retrieve data from the column current. Does anyone know why and how to fix it ?